# Unable to change Checked state of an CheckBox style UltraGridCell

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, infragistics, ultrawingrid

Using the `Infragistics` suite, I've taken over a project where there is a column that is `Checkbox` style, which represents a `Boolean` value in the database. I'm having trouble following the code that handles changing the value of it, as I've never come across anything like this before.

I only seem to be able to change the value of this column if I change the date in the 'Final Delivery' column first. However, the final delivery date has already been assigned a value before this stage in the process that I'm going through, so it can't be changed again.

Why does the following code not let me change the checked value unless I change the "Final_Delivery" value first?

```
   If e.Cell.Column.ToString = "Final_Delivery" Then
            e.Cell.Row.Update()
        End If

        If Replace(e.Cell.Column.ToString, "[hidden]", "").Trim = "Customer_Paid" Then
            e.Cell.Row.Update()

            If e.Cell.Value = True Then
                e.Cell.Row.Cells("PaymentDate").Value = Today
            End If

            End If
```

Comment: Is `Today` a boolean value?

Comment: @theBugger No, it's a date value

Comment: So, I don't see where you set the new boolean value

Comment: @theBugger The boolean value is set when the checkbox in `Customer_Paid` cell is clicked. However, I am unable to click the cell because it wants me to change the `Final_Delivery` date first. When I change the date, I can check it and it works fine, but at this point in the program, the `Final_Delivery` value has already been set. So, I need to adapt the code so a date isn't required to be entered first

Comment: *I am unable to click the cell because it wants me to change the Final_Delivery date first.* What does this mean?

Comment: @theBugger I am using an UltraGrid. The grid is displaying the columns/database fields. One of these columns, Customer_Paid, is a boolean in the DB, so is a checkbox style column in the grid. I am unable to change the checked state of the cell unless I enter a date for the Final_Delivery column first

Comment: It's because the row doesn't exist yet maybe?

Comment: The database row? It does exist, this is an ordering system. At this point, the order has been delivered, so this is just to check it off as paid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this where you set the layout/settings for the grid?

```
YourUltraGrid.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Override.CellClickAction = CellClickAction.Edit
```